# Quotient groups and Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

If the groups $2 \mathbb Z$ and $3 \mathbb Z$ are isomorphic, why the quotient groups $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \simeq \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z \simeq \mathbb Z_3$ are not isomorphic? What am I thinking wrongly? Thank you very much!!

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic groups and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are not. Why do you think there is something wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk of quotient groups $G/H$  we actually work with the specific *subset* $H$ in $G$, and that subset should be a normal subgroup. Replacing it by another subset yields a different quotient.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that $2 \mathbb Z$ and $3 \mathbb Z$ are isomorphic as subgroups of $\mathbb Z$.

The quotient groups are not isomorphic, because if they were, it would imply that they have the same number of elements: they don't have the same number of elements, one has 2 and the other has 3, hence a bijection can't exist between them, so an isomorphism can't exist between them.